# Can't implement two step definitions individually in cucumber

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, watir

I'm automating using cucumber and ruby. My scenario is as follows.

```
Given I'm on home page
When i click on links
Then it should redirect to corresponding pages.
```

To implement, I've done iterations to click all the links in the second step.

To do this, I've to go back to the home page each time and then to verify.  Do I have to repeat the second the step implementations each time or can I skip the third step and implement everything in the second step itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in a table see the following:

```
  Background: Member should open homepage
      Given member goes to home page

  @javascript
  Scenario: Member should go to correct url by clicking links in head menu
     Then member should ensure that links in the table go to correct url
        | Spor Giyim          | /spor-giyim            |
        | Kadın               | /kadin                 |
        | Erkek               | /erkek                 |
        | Ayakkabı & Çanta    | /ayakkabi-canta        |
```

Ruby part should be like this:

```
When(/^member should ensure that links in the table go to correct url$/) do |table|
    # table is a Cucumber::Core::Ast::DataTable
    links = table.raw

    links.each do |line|
        link       = line[0]
        target_url = line[1]

        click_link(link)

        url = page.current_url
        expect(url).to include target_url 
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. ll try this now.

Answer (score 1):

I like a slightly less imperative approach:

```
Given I am on home page
When I collect a list of links and the text from the header menu
Then visiting each link should return a page where the title matches the link text
```

Or maybe it matches the alt text, or you match the URLs or something along those lines. I think an imperative approach shown above makes it so that new items added to the page do not get checked, and anything falling off does get checked.

If you want to make it more imperative and have a list, I would verify that only those links show up and that it throws an error if a new link shows up unexpectedly.